# Middle Sidebar Advertising

Tags: discussion, advertising, announcement

As you all know, advertising is an important source of revenue for Stack Overflow and it helps us support all the sites across the Stack Exchange Network and the resources that go into maintaining and improving the experience on the platform. We are going to be introducing middle sidebar ads, which have been on the main Stack Overflow site for years, to some of the tech sites including Super User.

The middle sidebar ads have the same standards as any other ads on the platform. Ads are non-intrusive and static. Ads go through a vetting process to ensure they are appropriate for the communities on Stack Exchange. If you see an ad that may not follow our established standards and guidelines, you can let us know by using the "**report this ad**" functionality. Here is a mockup of what these will look like when two ads are showed (the existing ad placement and the new middle sidebar ad placement):

[image: sample of ads on the middle side bar of the site]

This ad space won’t be available for display until May 10 because we wanted to give you a heads-up before you started seeing them. Ads are an essential line of business for us and we’re committed to giving you advance notice whenever we introduce a new form of advertising on the network sites. If you have any questions or concerns, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the advanced notification :)

Comment: Ads don't bother me like they seem to many others in tech, but I'd be interested in seeing just how effective ads as a revenue model are on a site like SuperUser, where presumably a significant portion of users are using ad blockers.

Comment: Where will the ads be hosted? On a SE domain or from a 3rdparty domain?

Comment: **EDIT: This was posted before you clarified the above. Leaving it in place to show why I was confused and thought the remark cryptic.** It just seems as though you've got some information that would answer Hashim's question, but unless Hashim does make the unlikely step of going to work at one of those places, that information wasn't revealed. Is the proportion of blocker users smaller than expected? The blockers less effective than people think? Something else?

Comment: @HashimAziz probably at least well as it does on Stack Overflow where ad block usage is also likely to be heavy.  If anything, I'd guess this site gets more visits from less-technically inclined people who see ads because they don't know they can block them.

Comment: @Gantendo if memory serves - served via google, SE's not run its own adserver in years.